# Access parent variable

Tags: php, class, controller, scope

How should I access this variable ?

```
class BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $view = new Views;
        $view->layout = 'master';
    }
}
```

So I want to access $view on my other controller

```
class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function showForm()
    {
        // Access $view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you cannot. `$view` is a local variable in your function. But you can make it a [`protected` property](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) so it is not accessible from the outside but can be inherited:

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class
>   itself and by inherited and parent classes.

So your class would be like:

```
class BaseController
{
    protected $view;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = new Views;
        $this->view->layout = 'master';
    }
}
```

and then access it:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function showForm()
    {
        echo $this->view->layout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class BaseController {
    protected $view = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $view = new Views;
        $view->layout = 'master';
        $this->view = $view;
    }
}
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function showForm() {
        // Access $view
        echo parent::$view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view         = new Views;
        $this->view->layout = 'master';
    }
}

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function showForm()
    {
        echo $this->view->layout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define $view with protected in class and avoid this code because you increse the dependency

```
    class BaseController{
       public function __construct(){
         $view = new Views;
         $view->layout = 'master';
       }
    }
```

change you code to:

```
    class BaseController{
       protected $view;
       public function __construct($view = null){
          $this->view = $view;
          $this->view->layout = 'master';
      }
}



class HomeController extends BaseController{
   public function showForm(){
     echo parent::$view;
   }
}
```